# Logstash: Nested grok searches? Parsing a field into multiple fields?

Tags: parsing, logstash, logstash-grok

I have log entries that look like this...

```
2014-02-25 00:00:03,936 INFO  - something happened...bla bla bla
2014-02-25 00:00:03,952 INFO  - ***Request Completed*** [   78.002] mS [http://cloud.mydomain.local/schedule/search?param=45]
2014-02-25 00:00:04,233 INFO  - something else happened...bla bla bla
```

I have a grok filter that correctly parses the lines...

```
grok {
    match => [ "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate} %{WORD:severity}%{SPACE}- %{GREEDYDATA:body}" ]
}
```

I'd like to parse **additional data** out of 'body' if 'body' begins with "***Request Completed***". Namely the 'elaspsedms' and 'uri'. How can I do this?

Elsewhere it was suggested that I add another message entry to the grok filter like this...

```
grok {
    match => [ 
              "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate} %{WORD:severity}%{SPACE}- \*\*\*Request Completed\*\*\* \[%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:elaspedms}\] mS \[%{URI:uri}\]",
              "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate} %{WORD:severity}%{SPACE}- %{GREEDYDATA:body}"
             ]
}
```

...this works, but for timing lines, the value of 'body' does **NOT** get set.  Ideally I'd like body to **always** contain the last part of the entry and iff, the entry is a timing line, perform additional parsing of elapsedms and uri.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Is there a means to parse fields?  Such that I could attempt parse 'body' into elapsedms/uri, if that fails, continue.  Or is there a means to nest field matches in the grok expression?

Thoughts?

Edit: Rather than making sure 'body' is always set, could I just create body from 'elaspedms' and 'uri' if 'elaspedms' is set?

Answer (score 3):

This works.  Is there a better way?

```
grok {
   match => [ 
          "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate} %{WORD:severity}%{SPACE}- \*\*\*Request Completed\*\*\* \[%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:elaspedms}\] mS \[%{URI:uri}\]",
          "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate} %{WORD:severity}%{SPACE}- %{GREEDYDATA:body}"
         ]
}

# if body is NOT set (timing line) make one
if ![body] {
    mutate { 
        add_field => [ "body", "***Request Completed*** [%{elapsedms}] mS [%{uri}]"] 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better way that is known to work in Logstash 1.5.3:

```
grok {
   match => [ 
          "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate} %{WORD:severity}%{SPACE}- %{GREEDYDATA:body}"
         ]
}

# if body is set (which should always be true, but it's good to check anyway)
if [body] {
    grok {
       break_on_match => true
       match => [ 
          "body", "\*\*\*Request Completed\*\*\* \[%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:elaspedms}\] mS \[%{URI:uri}\]"
         ]
    }
}
```

This way, *every* record will have a `body` field, but only the lines that contain `"***Request Completed***"` will have `elapsedms` and `uri` fields. You can continue this logic with sub-sub fields and sub-sub-sub fields as far down into the weeds as you like.

I also included the `"break_on_match"` syntax in case that is helpful. You can set it to either `true` or `false`.

The key is to use the `body` field (or whichever field you're parsing) as the match source rather than `message`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use the `break_on_match` option within grok and set it to false: http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/grok#break_on_match